# Не получается открыть файл базы данных на aiogram,выдает ошибку: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, aiogram

*текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом*вот файл запуска:

## Запись в Базу Данных

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    if str(chat_id_bot) in str(message.chat.id):
        pass
    else:
        if message.from_user.username == None:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, '⛔️ Вам необходимо установить логин для работы с ботом!')
        else:
            func.first_join(user_id=chat_id, username=username)
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, '✅ Добро пожаловать, {}!'.format(message.from_user.first_name),
                                   reply_markup=kb.menu)
```

вот функция базы:

```
class GiveBalance:
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.login = user_id
        self.balance = None


def first_join(user_id, username):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
    q = connection.cursor()
    q = q.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IS ' + str(user_id))
    row = q.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        q.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (user_id, offers, balance, qiwi, ban, nick) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (
            user_id, '0', '0', 'Не указан', '0', username))
        connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если так работать с базами (особенно с sqlite3, которая просто файл к которой подключаетесь), то возможны всякие проблемы. У вас асихронный бот, поэтому лучше найдите асихронный клиент для базы. Насчет запросов в базу - у вас строки с данными построены руками и данные берете откуда-то извне это дорога к sql-инъекциям, да и запросы выглядят неряшливо. Используйте биндинги. Плюс, у вас сравнение идет через `is` а это оператор для сравнения с `null`, используйте `=`, пример: `q = q.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id])`

Comment: Запрос с биндингом, второй параметр в `execute` - кортеж с данными: `q.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, offers, balance, qiwi, ban, nick) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_id, '0', '0', 'Не указан', '0', username))`. Драйвер базы сам приведет его к тому типу, что понимает база, плюс сделает экранирование - представьте, если у вас в строке будет символ `'`, а вы вставляете его в строку с `'%s'`

Answer (score 0):

В основном файле с ботом

```
from ['название файла с созданием бд'] import *;

async def on_startup:
createbd() #незвание того где создаётся таблица
```

И в пуллинге
on_startup=on_startup